# Creating a permalink to a certain portlet state

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, permalinks

How do I generate a permalink to a certain state of a portlet?

I need something like `<portlet:renderUrl/>` but with a much more user-friendly output. I need smt like `portal.com/search?q=query` instead of `portal.com/web/guest/home?p_auth=ASDFGH&p_p_id=xviewer_WAR_xviewer_INSTANCE_Yz9i&p_p_lifecycle=....`

How do I do this in Liferay Portal 6.0.6 and Spring Portlet MVC ?

Kindest regards,
q

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to avoid cryptic URL in Liferay is to use FriendlyURL. Look at [documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/optional%3a-adding-friendly-url-mapping-to-the-portlet) and [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper).

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible in Spring MVC

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. The friendlyUrl mapper is transparent from portlet point of view. (and therefore from Spring point of view) Just look at the examples and try it yourself.

Comment: What would be the mapping of: `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_auth=49sdCHvU&p_p_id=viewer_WAR_viewer&p_p_lifecycle=1 &p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2 &p_p_col_count=1&_viewer_WAR_viewer_action=test1 &lastQuery=lastone` 




to a form like `http://localhost:8080/home/-/viewer/test1/lastone` ?